# C++ Using pointer across exe dll boundary

Tags: c++, dll, glfw

Im working with glfw specifically, but hopefully this is a general question about exe and dll boundaries.

Im trying to pass a GLFWwindow* from a dll to an exe in a windows dev env.

Here a simplified snippet:

```
*inside main.cpp in the exe:*
    GLFWwindow* w = dllClass.getGLFWWindowPointer() 
    int display_w, display_h;
    if (w)
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(w, &display_w, &display_h);
```

The pointer gets returned and is not null, that ..FramebufferSize func is being called, but the display_w is 0 after it runs. (and are correct when this same code is called by a class within the dll)

Note that the classes in the dll are marked with __declspec(dllexport). Looking at the glfw codebase, that GLFWwindow is a struct with a bunch of context info and the glfwGetFramebufferSize function itself within the glfw dll is also marked with __declspec(dllexport), not sure if that's particularly relevant.

I'm really fuzzy on exe and dll barrier specifics, and if the problem is in the glfw code or on my end, so unsure where to go next.

Comment: You can use a pointer returned from a dll in your application or dll that uses the other dll.

Comment: I have had problems in the old days with problems like this - but not recently.  What version of the compiler do you have?  Also, if the DLL statically links the C runtime library you might have two free lists for malloc so allocating and deallocating might all have to be done against the same C runtime.  But if it is all liked to use shared libraries that's probably not the problem.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Thanks for response. Im using MSVC with Visual Studio 19. But I ended up just wrapping the pointer in a class of my own and passing the class and that seems to work now. Its probably a better way to do it anyway, so I'm happy to move on.